# CRUD edit-delete not working in production enviroment

Tags: symfony

In a Symfony project I have some CRUDs that work fine in development mode, wherever, when I publish the site (when I say publish I do not make deployment, only copy the project to the server) in the production enviroment the CRUD when I update and delete items do not work and do not release any error.

Somebody told me that Symfony secures the whole proccess of the App in production only when "I do deployment". Is this true?

I debug the project, and this instruction, that constructs the values passed in the request into a "Form" object leaves the values passed in the request. For example, there is a field "name", and "name" in the Form object takes the old value.

```
$editForm->handleRequest($request);
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache after you upload your files to the server? Also, keep in mind that you can "run" your site in `prod` environment under your localhost as well, you just simply have to clear the cache when you change something.

Comment: I do "all clear cache" possible! thankss

Comment: I am not sure if understood a single word of what you said up there :-/ Can you clarify?

Comment: In the servers I clear the cache for both enviroments, dev and prod.

Comment: You should check the symfony 2 logs `/app/logs/prod.log`

Answer (score 0):

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```